Page numbering resetting along with Last page numbering
I'm new to LaTex and I’m trying to have some landscape pages in different .tex files in the middle of my document with independent page numbering. Each page has a header that states "Page X of Y". What I'm trying to do right now is to use \setcounter{page}{1} to reset page numbering in the beginning of each .tex file and then have a label of each last page (\label{LastPageTest1}), so I can call it in each one of my headers (Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPageTest1}). However, this is currently not working since I'm calling it before labelling it... Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance!
Here's my code:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % For KOMA page styling and options
\usepackage{geometry} % For custom page margins
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For header and footer customization
\usepackage{tabularx} % For flexible-width tables
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including graphics like logos
\usepackage{array} % For custom column alignments in tables
\usepackage{makecell} % For enhanced cell formatting
\usepackage{multirow} % For multi-row table cells
\usepackage{lastpage} % For referencing the last page

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\KOMAoptions{paper=a4}
\KOMAoptions{pagesize, paper=landscape,DIV=6}
\newgeometry{
  bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, top=3cm,
  headsep=1.5cm % Space between header and the body text
}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[C,CO,L,LO,R,RO]{} %% clear out all headers

\fancyhead[h]{ 
        \centering
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
        \renewcommand\cellalign{cc}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|m{5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{15cm}|L{4.4cm}|}
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{5.5cm}{\resizebox{4.87cm}{1.53cm}{\includegraphics{Images/Logos/SP_logo_pos_horizontal.jpg}}} & 
        \multirow{4}{15cm}{\makecell[c]{\fontsize{11}{10}\selectfont Environmental monitoring software for the pharmaceutical industry (ID SPS) \\ \\ \MakeUppercase{\DocName}}} &  \makecell[l]{\parbox[c][0.9cm][c]{3cm}{\fontsize{10}{14}\selectfont Document code:\\ \DocCode}}  \\ \cline{3-3} 
                                 &                                                                                             &  \makecell[l]{\parbox[c][0.8cm][c]{3cm}{\fontsize{10}{16}\selectfont Version: \FileVersion}}              \\ \cline{3-3} 
                                 &                                                                                             & \makecell[l]{\parbox[c][0.8cm][c]{3cm}{\fontsize{10}{16}\selectfont Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPageTest1}}}             \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
        }


\fancyfoot[C,CO,L,LO,R,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
 \fancyfoot[C]{}


\label{LastPageTest1}

\end{document}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Your MWE loads both scrlayer-scrpage and fancyhdr. The two packages are incompatible.

The lastpage package is to use  \pageref{LastPage} without having to set the  LastPage label (or any other). You can also obtain the number (not the cross-reference) with  \PreviousTotalPages, without any package nor label, to obtain the true total of pages, no matter the page counter is.

If I use \pageref{LastPage} it writes the last page of the whole document, rather than the last page of the section I want the page numbering to be reset. I mean, I want the last page number to reset along with the \setcounter{page}{1}
